# Как авторизоваться на сайте через пост запрос, возможно ли в принципе?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, защита

На сайте установлен вход по паролю, временно, можно ли как то http хедерами авторизоваться тут, чтобы сайт обрабатывал входящие запросы (REST) ???
[image: Защита паролем]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, нужно добавить Authorization: Basic <шифрованный логинпароль>
в curl можно добавить типа  curl --user login:pass. Но как добавить теперь туда еще одну авторизацию (токен api) я хз, буду смотреть